# Can someone help me in writing this same program using CALL BY ADDRESS?

Tags: c++

This is a program i wrote to convert lower case string to upper case using CALL BY REFERENCE.

```
//program to convert a lower case sentence to upper case
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void changetoup(string &str)
{
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
    {
        str[i]-=32;  //line1
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"enter the sentence"<<endl;
    getline(cin,str);
    changetoup(str);
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Why don't you give it a go? Did you encounter some problem?

Comment: Incidentally, what do you intend the function will do if passed a string that contains any characters that are not lower case?  Or if the host system doesn't use a ANSI-compatible character set?

Comment: Also turn on your compiler warnings and heed them.

Comment: If you're not sure how to do this, it sounds like you need to schedule office hours with your instruction staff.

Comment: @Francesco to convert it to call by address. That is the question

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i dont know how to convert the line that i have marked as "line1"

Comment: @KaranarjunJr. So, you're _really_ asking how to use the `[]` operator on a `std::string*`? The rest of the question is irrelevant to that. Please be clearer about your question in future.

Comment: @KaranarjunJr. There is no such thing as "call-by-address" in C++.  It's either call-by-value, or call-by-reference.  A pointer is a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace the `str[i]` call to fit a pointer `str`, recall that the string itself is now described `*str`.

So you can:

1. Dereference there and then: `(*str)[i]`
2. Or make a reference:

   ```
   std::string& ref = *str;
   ref[i] -= 32;
   ```
3. Use [`at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at) instead (though this is slightly more costly, and can throw an exception, due to added bounds checking):

   ```
   str->at(i) -= 32;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```cpp
//program to convert a lower case sentence to upper case
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void changetoup(string *str)
{
    for(int i=0;i<(*str).length();i++)
    {
        str[0][i] -= 32; // or (*str)[i]
    }
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    cout<<"enter the sentence"<<endl;
    getline(cin,str);
    changetoup(&str);
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please dont mistaken me. I am a newbie and i dont understand why you are treating it like a 2D array

Comment: @KaranarjunJr. • C++ does not distinguish a pointer to an object from a pointer to an array of objects.  So `str[0][i]` is the same as `(*str)[i]`, because `str[n]` is equivalent to `*(str + n)` (and that is equivalent to `n[str]`, which looks odd, but works too).

Comment: @Eljay exactly!

Comment: You should also replace `(*str).length()` with `str->length()`

Comment: @SaiSreenivas semantically, they are identical, but `->` is just cleaner, and is what most everyone uses when accessing members via pointers